# Digital Multimeter not working on higher frequency

Tags: ac, multimeter, frequency-measurement

I have an ordinary multi-meter which looks like the one below in the description. When i measure higher frequencies above 200kHZ the voltage is not showing up properly as it says on the frequency generator? Are this kind of multi-meters designed for DC voltage and have problem with high AC voltage? 
I also have a related question i am not sensing the voltage on my tongue when it is at higher frequencies. Is the voltage really decreasing or it is not sensible it won't zap easily at higher frequencies?

[image: My Multimeter Model]

Comment: What does the datasheet or manual of the multimeter say?

Comment: It is lost. I couldn't find that.

Comment: You can just build an envelope detector (2 components, diode + cap) if you're curious about the amplitude and just measure in DC. You wouldn't need to put a resistor in parallel with the capacitor since the multimeter has a very high impedance which the capacitor can discharge slowly through.

Answer (score 2):

The AC range on most cheap multimeters is primarily designed to measure 50/60 Hz AC, like you would get out of an electrical outlet. [The only specifications I could find for that model of meter](https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/dt9205a-multimeter-manual) specify the AC range as being good for "40 ~ 400 Hz".

If you want to measure the amplitude of a higher frequency signal -- including any signal which includes *components* at higher frequencies! -- you will need to use a different instrument.

(As an aside, your body is not a voltmeter. Do not use your fingers or tongue to attempt to measure voltages -- it is not an effective means of measurement, and you will injure yourself when you inevitably try to measure an unexpectedly high voltage.)

Comment: I see. But until i get an oscilloscope, wasn't the voltage suppose to electrocute my skin? It electrocutes me at lower frequencies but not on higher ones.

Comment: @iamnamrud Stop doing that. You're going to hurt yourself.

Comment: I am not trying to measure it. I know it is not a safe practice. I was only checking it's existence.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, high voltages don't care if you're trying to measure them or just check their existence when you touch them - they'll kill you either way.

Comment: Using yourself as a test instrument is equivalent to completing your entry for a Darwin Award : so STOP....